# How I could open a new git bash terminal in the vscode panel (if there is not an active one) and make it active terminal VSCode Extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, terminal, vscode-extensions, git-bash

I am writing a visual studio code extension and at some point, when I call a command, I want to open a new git bash terminal and send a sh command. I use this now:
`vscode.window.activeTerminal?.sendText("the sh command")`
But the thing is that I do not want to use the active terminal, I want to open a new git bash terminal, make it active and send the sh command. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/chencn/yarn-ui/blob/master/src/extension.ts

```
    private get terminal() {
        if (!this.packagePath) {
            throw new Error('Trying to launch a terminal for a project with no package.json');
        }
        if (typeof this._terminal === 'undefined') {
            this._terminal = window.createTerminal({
                name: `Yarn UI - ${this.label}`,
                cwd: path.dirname(this.packagePath),
            });
        }
        this.ctx.subscriptions.push(
            window.onDidCloseTerminal(t => {
                if (t === this._terminal) {
                    this._terminal.dispose();
                    this._terminal = undefined;
                }
            }),
        );
        return this._terminal;
    }

    public runInTerminal(command: string) {
        try {
            this.terminal.show();
            this.terminal.sendText(command);
            if (!this.terminalReuseMessageShown) {
                this.terminal.sendText(`"This terminal will be re-used for yarn scripts of this project (${this.label})."`);
                this.terminalReuseMessageShown = true;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            window.showErrorMessage(`Failed to run ${command}`);
        }
    }
}
```